upgrading to ionic 8 & standalone component error alert controller
I have upgraded my application from ionic  7 to 8
After upgrading i am getting below error
ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(Environment Injector)[_ModalController -> _ModalController]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for _ModalController!
    at NullInjector.get (core.mjs:1654:27)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:3093:33)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:3093:33)
    at ChainedInjector.get (core.mjs:15723:36)
    at lookupTokenUsingModuleInjector (core.mjs:5730:39)
    at getOrCreateInjectable (core.mjs:5778:12)
    at Module.ɵɵdirectiveInject (core.mjs:11050:19)
    at NodeInjectorFactory.TabsPage_Factory [as factory] (tabs.page.ts:26:22)
    at getNodeInjectable (core.mjs:5984:44)
    at createRootComponent (core.mjs:15998:35)

Later i have found that issue related to stanalone component
https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/28385
as per suggestession above i ahve addedd
import { defineCustomElement as defineModal } from '@ionic/core/components/ion-modal.js';
defineModal();//constructor call
Same error i am getting >please some one suggest

The reason you are getting this error is because you aren't importing it properly for standalone components.
import { ModalController } from '@ionic/angular/standalone';

then use the old way:
constructor(private modalCtrl: ModalController) {};

or use new way:
private modalCtrl: ModalController = inject(ModalController);

